# JQuery Submit Form From Inside Submit Function

Tags: jquery, form-submit

The following is what I'd like to do in my JQuery script. In the submit function (4th) below, I want to decide if the form has file input and submit with either ajax or just a regular form submit without ajax. In other words, if the form has upload, do a regular submit.

I wrote the question in the submit function below. That is the only thing I need to make it work.

Thank you!

```
function FindFileInput(){
   // check for file input
   var FileInput = $('input:file');
   if(FileInput.length > 0){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}

function validation(){
  // code to validate form
  ...
}

function ajaxSubmit(formData){
   $.ajax({
      // ajax submit code
   });
}

$(myForm).submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   // 1. if NO file input present
   if(FindFileInput() === false){
      if(validation() === true){
         // serialize and call ajaxSubmit function
      }
   }

   // 2. if file input IS present
   if(FindFileInput() === true){
      if(validation() === true){
         // QUESTION: How do I submit the form here???
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/submit/:

> Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens
>   prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by
>   calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false
>   from our handler. We can trigger the event manually when another
>   element is clicked:

So turn your logic around. Don't call e.preventDefault() as default and then try to undo it, but rather only call it when it is actually needed.

```
$(myForm).submit(function(e){

    // 1. if NO file input present
    if(FindFileInput() === false){
        if(validation() === true){
            ajaxSubmit(formdata);
        }
     }

     // 2. if file input IS present
     if(FindFileInput() === true){
         if(validation() === true){
             return true; // submit form as normal, don't call e.preventDefault()
         }
     }

     // Prevent form from submitting normally
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The above suggestion worked as well, but this makes more sense from a programming and learning point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the submit to continue just don't prevent the default behavior and return true.

```
$(myForm).submit(function(e){

    if(!FindFileInput()){
        if(validation()){
            //AJAX method
        }
    }else{
        if(validation()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the `e.preventDefault()` so early, do it only when you actually want to stop the form from being posted the default way (thus, when a file is selected). That way you can get rid of the second if-statement, and just let the submit JS-function do nothing when there is a file to send. That way the form will be sent the default way, if no file is selected.

```
$(myForm).submit(function(e){

   // 1. if NO file input present
   if(FindFileInput() === false){
      if(validation() === true){
         e.preventDefault();
         // Do your AJAX-stuff here
      }
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.submit()` provided that you haven't overridden it with something like `<input name="submit" />`

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4buHP/

The native `.submit()` doesn't fire the jQuery event.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! I removed e.preventDefault(); and added some else conditions. However I provided a very procedural (less ideal) solution.

```
$(myForm).submit(function(e){

   // 1. if NO file input present
   if(FindFileInput() === false){
      if(validation() === true){
         // serialize and call ajaxSubmit function

         return false; // stops form submissions, same as preventDefault but less chars.
      }
   }

   // 2. if file input IS present
   if(FindFileInput() === true){
      if(validation() === true){
         // QUESTION: How do I submit the form here???
         // no return false, moves forward.
      } else {
          return false;
      }
   } else {
      return false;
   }
});
```